# Blender armature controls real time?

Tags: python-3.x, game-engine, blender

I'm new to blender and python I need to control armature in blender game engine via a serial data comes from arduino. I'm used this code but it does not work

```
import GameLogic

arm = GameLogic.getCurrentController().owner

print(arm.channels['Upperleg.L'].rotation_euler)

arm.channels['Upperleg.L'].rotation_euler = [5, 5, 5] arm.update()

print(arm.channels['Upperleg.L'].rotation_euler)
```

I'm using blender 2.71 and used always sensor with the python controller(script).I Can't find whats wrong in this code.Does any one knows how to change the eular angles of the armature in blender game engine mode?

Comment: What is the error? `arm.update()` should be placed on a new line.

Comment: It's prints outs euler vector values but my bones in the armature does not move in blender geme engine.I'm using always sensor connected to the the python controller.